# Stored procedure is not returning rows with dynamic query, Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper

I've created a stored procedure with dynamic query. The values are returned to my app in C# with Dapper.

The following code works, the rows are returned to my app and are shown in SQL Server.

```
set @query = 'Select * from invoices';
exec sp_executesql @query
```

But when I build the query, something like this:

Dynamic query build:

```
'SELECT * FROM Invoices AS i    
 LEFT JOIN InvoiceInformations AS ii ON i.InvoiceId = ii.InvoiceId  
 WHERE 1 = 1';

exec sp_executesql @query
```

The rows are displayed correctly in SQL Server, but in C#, I got nothing.

It's important to say that it only happens when I build the query dynamically, but the query is ok, I printed it, run it manually and it works.

C# code (this works):

```
var invoices = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<Invoices>("sp_get_invoices", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Please help!!

Comment: Can you share the code for your procedure? Also, you should consider not using sp_ as a prefix. Either choose something different, or even better no prefix at all. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: I'm not sure that you can apply an alias to a join using "AS" - try chaining LEFT JOIN InvoiceInformations as ii to LEFT JOIN InvoiceInformations ii

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved it, I was looking in the stored procedure but it was ok.
the problem was in the parameters of Dapper.

I had some values NOT NULLABLES, like InvoiceId

```
var invoices = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<Invoices>("sp_get_invoices",
                    new 
                    {
                        InvoiceId = filter.InvoiceId,
                        Currency = filter.Currency
                    }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

my stored procedure verifies:

```
if (InvoiceId IS NOT NULL)
  SET @Query = @Query + ' AND i.InvoiceId = ' + CAST(@InvoiceId as varchar(10));
```

I just nullable it on C#

```
        public int? InvoiceId { get; set; }
```